# C2511: overloaded member function not found (in Release mode only)

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using VS2008 to design a MFC application. It's very good in Debug mode. But when I switch to Release mode,  it throw error

```
error C2511: 'CCESDoc *CCESView::GetDocument(void) const' : overloaded member function not     found in 'CCESView'
```

This code definition of CCESView.h file

```
#ifndef _DEBUG 
inline CCESDoc* CCESView::GetDocument() const 
{ 
    return reinterpret_cast<CCESDoc*>(m_pDocument);
}
#endif
```

When I remove this definition, it do not throw error when I compile, but when I'm running, it have other error R6034: **An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library without using manifest**

Comment: Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20fs9x81.aspx

Comment: Thank your reply
why it is success in Debug mode ?

Comment: "How to Fixed it!" is grammatically incorrect. Also, it's considered rude to write this here. You've written your question here. We kind of can guess you want to know "how to fix it".

Comment: thank you for your comments. !!  ..
But why it is successed in Debug mode ?

Comment: No problem. Also "why it is success" is not correct. You should say "why is it successful" instead.

Comment: hi. I'm speak english not well.
I'm sorry !

Comment: Maybe the function declaration in the header file is inside an `#ifdef _DEBUG`?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't say much without header file for the `CCESView` class.

Comment: Yes, we need to see the full definition of `CCESView` and the code where `CCESView::GetDocument` is called before we can offer any useful suggestions.

Comment: This code definition of CCESView.h file
'#ifndef _DEBUG  // debug version in CESView.cpp
inline CCESDoc* CCESView::GetDocument() const
  { return reinterpret_cast<CCESDoc*>(m_pDocument); }
#endif'

When I remove this definition, it do not throw error when I compile, but when I'm running, it have other error 
**R6034: An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library without using manifest**

Comment: Are we have any other idea ?